# CGAffineTransformRotate issue with image

Tags: ios, swift, animation, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to create a very simple clock. When I apply a CGAffineTransformRotate it looks great, however on the 30th - 31st second the hand goes crazy.

[An example of it going wrong.](http://i.imgur.com/WjwJzCQ.gifv)

Here is the code I'm using to animate it:

```
    lengthInSeconds += 1
    let angle = CGFloat(6.degreesToRadians * Double(lengthInSeconds))
    var transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, (clockFace.frame.width/4))

    secondsHand.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle)

    let spring = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    spring.damping = 2.0//3.0
    spring.duration = 0.4
    spring.mass = 0.1
    spring.initialVelocity = 0.0

    secondsHand.layer.addAnimation(spring, forKey: "rotation")
    secondsHand.transform = transform
```

Anyone have any idea as to why it would rotate awkwardly like this? Just to add, it happens on all passes, so at 30 seconds, 1 minute 30, 2 minutes 30 etc.